# nested formarray within group angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Good Day.

I looked for the solution, and even though there are a view similar question to what I am asking, I am sure this one is a bit more unique and not a duplicate.

here is my html form:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" formGroupName="schema">
  <div formArrayName="currencies">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percentage" formControlName="percentage" placeholder="Discount %*" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my ts formBuilder.

```
this.createPromo = this.fb.group({
      type: ['promotion'],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      enabled: ['', Validators.required],
      promotion_type: ['', Validators.required],
      start: ['', Validators.required],
      end: ['', Validators.required],
      schema: this.fb.group({
        currencies: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
            percentage: '',
            currency: 'ZAR'
          })
        ])
      }),
    });
```

So I want my form to submit as a grouped array. However the error in the console is the following `Cannot find control with path: 'schema -> currencies -> percentage'`, thus I am not able to submit my form as `percentage` is empty even after I input a number.

Comment: You'll need a wrapping `div` with `formArrayName="currencies"` and inside that another `[formGroup]="i"` where I would be the index of the array elements you loop through, and then inside that, you'll have your `formControlName="percentage"` and `formControlName="currency"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need the following for your scenario:

1. A parent `div` with `formGroupName="schema"`.
2. Inside that, a `div` with `formArrayName="currencies"`.
3. Inside that, a `div` with `ngFor="let currencyGroup of currencyFormGroups; let i = index;"`. Notice that `currencyFormGroups` is a getter in your Component Class.
4. Inside that, a `div` with `[formGroupName]="i"` where `i` is the index that we created on the fly within `*ngFor`.
5. Insde that, two `input`s with `formControlName="percentage"` and `formControlName="currency"` respectively.

.

Here's all these steps translated to code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  createPromo: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createPromo = this.fb.group({
      'type': ['type'],
      name: ['name', Validators.required],
      description: ['description', Validators.required],
      enabled: ['enabled', Validators.required],
      promotion_type: ['promotion_type', Validators.required],
      start: ['start', Validators.required],
      end: ['end', Validators.required],
      schema: this.fb.group({
        currencies: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
            percentage: 'percentage',
            currency: 'ZAR'
          }),
          this.fb.group({
            percentage: 'percentage',
            currency: 'INR'
          }),
        ])
      }),
    });
  }

  get currencyFormGroups() {
    return (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>this.createPromo.get('schema')).get('currencies')).controls;
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="createPromo">

  ...

  <div formGroupName="schema">
    <div formArrayName="currencies">
      <div *ngFor="let currencyGroup of currencyFormGroups; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="percentage"
            formControlName="percentage">
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="currency"
            formControlName="currency">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-eg-with-currency?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

**PS:** For simplicity's sake, I've considered all the form controls as `input`. Please make your changes accordingly.